# Падает тест java.lang.AssertionError

Tags: java, junit

При использовании Assert.assertEquals падает тест, из-за того что после листа expected добавляется пробел(непонятно почему).

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
IndexList<Integer> indexList = new IndexList<>();
indexList.add(a);
indexList.add(b);
indexList.add(c);
IndexList<Integer> expected = new IndexList<>();
expected.add(b);
expected.add(c);
indexList.remove(0);
Assert.assertEquals(expected, indexList);
```

Падает тест с ошибкой:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: IndexList<2 3 > but was: impl.IndexList<2 3 >
Expected :impl.IndexList<2 3 >*в этом месте пробел* 
Actual   :impl.IndexList<2 3 >
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?
Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А что за класс такой `IndexList`? От чего он наследуется? Это ваш класс?

Посмотрите код `assertEquals` у [`Assert`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Assert.java). Если `IndexList` это ваш класс и там нет перегрузки `equals`, то `assertEquals` вроде как просто ссылки сравнивает.

Comment: забыл equlas переопределить)

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что проблема в работе класса IndexList.